# Class number 1 for negative integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

If n is a positive integer then, $h(-4n) = 1 \iff n = 1,2,3,4,7$. The only proof I have seen of this is long and case wise. Is there any conceptual a priori reason to believe that these numbers are exceptional with regards to class number?

Comment: Probably not. We do have formulas that tell us the class numbers of imaginary quadratic fields tends to infinity, so the list should be finite; but that doesn't tell us why exactly this finite. And some of these small fields are Euclidean domains, which implies class number 1, but not all I believe.